# Best way to pass username and password from one page to another

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the best way to pass username and password from one page to another?

I have used session to store and retrieve username and password but i feel its not the best practice.

```
Session["name"] = name;
```

Could anyone suggest me a better way to do this.

Comment: Please clarify why existing authentication solutions don't  work for you and what are specific criteria your solution need to satisfy. There is no way to suggest "better" approaches without this information.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov first of all i am just checking if there is any other approach to do so? If session times out then the username and password wont be saved and it has to be redirected to the login screen. Is it possible to do using sessions so basically i dont want any timeouts

Answer (score 0):

By passing i am not sure what you mean.

It would make sense that on the first page, password and username are posted to some sort of backend and stored(hash in terms of pw) in some form.

Then on the load of the next page, an identifier is used to retrieve the relevant details for that page, by making a call to the same backend, that retrieves from your data store and then is returned in some sort of model to the View.

I know this is very vague, but gives a general idea.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: is it possible for you to give a demo of this?

Comment: mmm that would be quite a lot haha. I would recommend looking into videos around building a simple asp.net application end to end such as a simple todo app.

Comment: there are plenty of videos our there with good explanations. good luck :)